# Empty page within ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, emptypage

I am using the following document setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=32mm, inner=32mm, outer=24mm, bottom=32mm, 
 headsep=10mm,footskip=12mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
```

Additionally, I manually insert empty pages after ToC, list of figures, etc. because I do not want to print them double-sided.

However, my ToC is over 2 pages and, hence, I need an empty page in between the two ToC pages.

How can I set that up?

Comment: Please show a compilable document, not just fragments

Answer (score 2):

With `\addcontentsline` you can add the commands for making a blank page, having them `\protect`ed first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}
  \subsection{A}
  \subsection{B}
\section{Two}
  \subsection{C}
  \subsection{D}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\newpage\null\protect\newpage}

\section{Three}
  \subsection{E}
  \subsection{F}
\section{Four}
  \subsection{G}
  \subsection{H}

\end{document}
```

If you also want to get rid of the page number, add `\protect\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\null`.